# Error: No ESLint configuration found in /Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, eslint, eslintrc

I have this error with eslint. I am working with vue/vuex. This is my stacktrace:

```
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
> Error: No ESLint configuration found in
> /Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/store.
>     at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (/Users/anme/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:432:19)
>     at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (/Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:271:21)
>     at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (/Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:951:18)
>     at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:868:38)
>     at lint (/Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:278:17)
>     at transform (/Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:252:18)
>     at /Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:127:18
>     at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/name/Desktop/blognewtonmcvue/mevnexample/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:31:14)
>     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (node:fs:273:13)
```

One of the solutions I tried was to use

> eslint --init

and then i got this file:

eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/essential"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

But the error points to my  store files  posts.js and store.js

post.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import vuex from "vuex";

const state = {
  posts: [],
};

const getters = {
  allPosts: (state) => state.Posts,
};

const actions = {
  //an action: makes a request, gets a response and calls a mutation
  async fetchPosts({ commit }) {
    // commit - to call the mutation
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/posts");
    commit("setPosts", response.data);
  },
  async addPosts({ commit }, title) {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/posts/add", {
      title,
      completed: false,
    });
    commit("newPost", response.data);
  },
  async deletePosts({ commit }, id) {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/delete/${id}`);
    commit("removePosts", id);
  },
  async filterPosts({ commit }, e) {
    //Get selected number
    // const limit = parseInt(e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].innerText);
    const limit = e.target.value;
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts`);
    commit("setPosts", response.data);
  },
  async updatePosts({ commit }, updatePosts) {
    const response = await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:4000/posts/update/${this.$route.params.id}`,
      updatePosts
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    commit("updatePosts", response.data);
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setPost: (state, posts) => (state.posts = posts),
  newPost: (state, posts) => state.posts.unshift(posts),
  removePost: (state, id) =>
    (state.posts = state.posts.filter((posts) => posts.id !== id)),
  updatePosts: (state, updPosts) => {
    const index = state.Posts.findIndex((posts) => posts.id === updPosts.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      state.posts.splice(index, 1, updPosts);
    }
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};

//this is a boilerplate for vuex module
```

This is my other file. Both store.js and post.js files are in the directory/map "store"

store.js

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";
import store from "./post";

//load Vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

//create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    post,
  },
});
```

I have babel.config.js
.eslintrc.js in my project

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by this steps.

1. npm uninstall eslint (because i had the wrong version)
2. npm install eslint@7.11.0(did this because it supported es2021)
   If this steps do not work try to clone your project again from github